# Converting a C++ inline assembler function to delphi inline assembler function

Tags: c++, c, delphi, assembly

please how could this C++ function be converted to Delphi  :

```
int To_Asm_Fnc(dword Amem, dword Al, dword Ac) {
int b = 0;
    asm ("push %%ecx; \
             call %%eax; \
             pop  %%ecx;"
         : "=Al" (b) /* output value */
         : "Al" (mem), "Ac" (Al), "d" (Ac) /* input value */
         );
    return b;
}
```

and this's my delphi attempt

```
Function To_Asm_Fnc(Amem,Al,Ac:dword):Integer;
var
b:Integer;
begin
Result:=0;
b:=0;
//*******
{ i really didn't get it as in the c++ code }
//*******
Result:=b;
end;
```

many thanks

Comment: This is not C++, this is assembly.

Comment: What's your C++ compiler. You need to know the calling convention and register preserving rules for that convention to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: In Delphi you can use `asm` keyword too, http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Inline_Assembly_Code.

Comment: @Pol What you say is true but there's more to it than that. Do you know what particular blend of asm is in play in the C++ code?

Comment: This question is so narrow and useless that it's not worth having on the site.   If you put some effort into asking a smarter question, then it could have both helped you, and other people.     Why not, for example, take the C++ code, compile it with a compiler, and dump the ASM listing, and then use the bare ASM listing to show what the crazy macro-string-assembler syntax actually does in your C++ compiler?

Comment: I've voted to reopen.  I disagree with the close votes. I don't see what's wrong with the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

seems this function accepts a pointer to another function and sets up the parameters

```
function To_Asm_Fnc(Amem: Pointer; _Al, _Ac: cardinal): integer;
asm
  // x68 only!; paramateres are passed differently in x64
  // inputs : "Al" (mem), "Ac" (Al), "d" (Ac) /* input value */
  // amem is already in eax
  // _al is passed in edx and _ac in ecx; but the code expects them reversed
  xchg edx, ecx
  push ecx
  call eax
  pop  ecx
  // result is already in eax and delphi returns the result in eax
  // outputs : "=Al" (b) /* output value */
end;
```

Comment: If all this routine is doing is reversing the order of the parameters, it may be better in the long run to do that without resorting to assembly. I must say I can't quite see how you have discerned that the original asm reverses the two parameters.

Comment: original asm didn't reverse the parameters. the code: "Ac" (Al), "d" (Ac) means: put the Al variable into the ecx register and Ac variable into the edx register. delphi pases the params in the follwing order: eax, edx, ecx, stack; so to keep the function signature the same, we swap the passed parameters. ps. the function calls another function pointed to by Amem parameter

Comment: Out of interest, which C++ compiler accepts asm in this format. I don't recognise that syntax. Oh, +1 by the way.

Comment: it's GCC and that kind of param passing/mapping is "Extended ASM".

Comment: Thanks for that. FWIW, I think your answer would have benefited from containing that explanation as to what the compiler was, what the syntax was, what the param mapping was and a little detail of what the original code did and what your Pascal code does. I suspect it would have got more upvotes and the Q might not have been closed.